# EF Code First Migrations Developer Conflicts

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

We are running into some conflicts when using EF Migrations with 2 or more developers.  I'm curious if anyone has a better solution than what we ended up with to resolve these issues.  First, here is the scenario:

2 Developers, Dev1 and Dev2:

**The problem:**

1. Dev1 and Dev2 both make model changes simultaneously in their
   working copies of the application.
2. Dev1 and Dev2 both create a
   migration (add-migration) and update their local database so they
   can test (update-database).
3. Dev1 finishes and checks his code in first.
4. Dev2 checks out the code from Dev1 and runs update-database.
5. Dev2 gets an error, saying there are outstanding changes.  These
   "outstanding" changes are the changes that were previously applied
   in his own migration but are now unaccounted for after applying
   Dev1's migration, even though the changes actually have already been
   applied.  It seems that the model validation is confused, thinking those changes were never applied as a result of applying Dev1's migration.

**Our solution:**
Dev2 creates a new migration and empties out the Up() and Down() methods, then runs update-database.  This gets everything back in sync again.

This solution works, however it results in many empty migrations that have no purpose except to get the model hashes back in sync.  Has anyone had similar issues and found another way around them?  Or are we using the database migrations incorrectly?

Comment: I think if you were working from the same database you wouldn't have this problem. Of course you would have a lot of other different problems. this because the deltas in migration are calculated from what are different databases when you attempt to apply them.

Comment: You might want to keep an eye on http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/760 and http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/780

Comment: We ended up finding a solution nearly exactly what was described in your link in the third comment.  If you want to toss that into an answer, I'll accept it as yours since you brought the info here.